# Angular ngGrid data presentation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, plunker

I'm new to Angular and my experience with Javascript is not very extensive. I am failing to show data in ngGrid using following code. What is the problem?

In essence. I am loading data from a web-service, performing a transform (pivot) on it and then I want to present it in a grid.

Please see the following

app.js -> starting poing

```
var konstruktApp= angular.module('konstruktApp',['ngGrid']);
```

dataService.js -> web service call

```
'use strict';
konstruktApp.service('DataService',function DataService($http){
   var callHttp = function(){
     delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
       return $http.get("http://83.250.197.214/konstrukt.service/Konstrukt.SL.DummyBudgetService.svc/GetDummyBudgetData/");
   };
    return {
        getDummyData: callHttp
    };
});
```

ngGridController.js -> where the logic resides...

```
$scope.getData = DataService.getDummyData;
$scope.gridOptions = {data:'result'};
var getData = function() {
    $scope.getData().then(function (response) {
        var res = pivotData(response.data);
        $scope.result = res.data.PivotedRows;

        $scope.columns = res.cols;

        console.log('from the success handler at ' + new Date());
    }, function (reason) {
        console.log('failed: ');
        console.log(reason);
    });

};
```

..and here is the logic that "pivots" the data

```
var pivotData = function(data) {
  var firstColumn = "Dim1";
  var secondColumn = "Period";

  var columns = [];
  columns.push({
    field: firstColumn,
    enableCellEdit: false
  });


  var pivotedArray = {};

  pivotedArray.PivotedRows = [];
  var rowItems = [];
  var rowArray = {};

  var previusFirstColumnValue = -1;
  var firstColumnValue = 1;

  //for each row
  for (var i = 0; i < data.Rows.length; i = i + 1) {
    //firstColumnValue = $scope.dataCollection.Rows[i].FindCell.Cells[firstColumn].Value;
    firstColumnValue = findCell(data.Rows[i].Cells, firstColumn).Value;

    //var secondColumnValue = data.Rows[i].Cells[secondColumn].Value;
    var secondColumnValue = findCell(data.Rows[i].Cells, secondColumn).Value;
    //if first column value has changed, add new row
    if (firstColumnValue != previusFirstColumnValue) {

      if (i !== 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < rowItems.length; j = j + 1) {
          rowArray[rowItems[j].name] = rowItems[j].value;
        }
        pivotedArray.PivotedRows.push( rowArray);
        rowArray = {};
        rowItems = [];
      }

      rowItems.push({
        name: firstColumn,
        //value: $scope.dataCollection.Rows[i].Cells[firstColumn].Value
        value: findCell(data.Rows[i].Cells, firstColumn).Value
      });
    }

    //if (columns.indexOf({field: secondColumnValue}) == -1) {
    if (i < 12) {
      columns.push({
        field: secondColumnValue,
        editableCellTemplate: "<input ng-class=\"'colt' + col.index\" ng-input=\"COL_FIELD\" ng-blur=\"lostFocus()\" ng-model=\"COL_FIELD\" ng-change=\"dataChanged(col,row,row.entity)\"/>",
        enableCellEdit: true
      });
    }

    rowItems.push({
      name: secondColumnValue,
      value: findCell(data.Rows[i].Cells, secondColumn).Value
    });
    previusFirstColumnValue = firstColumnValue;
  }


  for (var k = 0; k < rowItems.length; k = k + 1) {
    rowArray[rowItems[k].name] = rowItems[k].value;
  }

 // $scope.columns = columns;

  pivotedArray.PivotedRows.push( rowArray);

  return {data: pivotedArray, cols: columns};
};
```

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZqC7696xGbUtuWGIvnYs?p=preview

**EDIT: The data correlation rows<-> columns is correct, I suspect there is something wrong with data in the pivotedArray.PivotedRows array.**

Comment: First of, do you get the data? Did you try seeing what you get with Fiddler

Comment: hi, yes I get the data. It looks fine. I debugged the plnkr code in chrome and have verified that... So something goes wrong in the transformation, but I am getting the data transformed correctly but perhaps some of my datatypes are incorrect to use with ngGrid!?

Comment: Fixed your plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/HbubRoZD5jj13vbgakwM?p=preview Data is now showing

Comment: This just isnt my day. Use http://plnkr.co/edit/ZqC7696xGbUtuWGIvnYs?p=preview instead. Obviously I have to fork also...

Comment: I moved the code to a new plnkr and then it worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that moving the code to a new plnkr made the difference.  Now, thats a few hours of my life that I want back :)